# JS/TS Difference bewteen function definitions in object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

A specific problem fixed was one of function declaration mismatch. I am wondering, in my specific case, what the difference between

```
const obj => {
  thing1: () => void //This is type thing1: () => undefined
  thing2(){ return; }  //This is type  thing2(): void
};
```

I do not see any difference between the two. One is an object attribute that contains a lambda function and the other is a function declared in the object. Why are they different types?

Comment: What TypeScript version are you using, and can you reproduce this in a playground? Both should have the same `void` return type.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is invalid, but I'm going to assume your meant this:

```
const obj = {
  thing1: () => undefined,
  thing2() { return },
};
```

The type of `thing1` is:

```
(property) thing1: () => undefined
```

This is a property of `obj` that has a value of a function. That function is an arrow function that returns `undefined`. Arrow functions capture the value of `this` from the declaring scope. So `this` could be anything, from the type only can't tell. However, what this does tell you is that you don't need to be concerned with the value of `this` since it's bound in the function declaration itself. This means you could break it off and pass it as a callback like:

```
obj.thing1() // `this` is whatever `this` was when the function was declared.

const fn = obj.thing1
fn() // `this` is whatever `this` was when the function was declared.
```

---

`thing2` is typed as:

```
(method) thing2(): void
```

In this case `thing2` is a *method* of `obj` that returns a value that should not be used. In reality it's `undefined`, but as far as type is concerned, it returns an unusable return value.

And here `this` is not bound for you, and is instead set by calling syntax:

```
obj.thing2()
// ^ this dot sets the value of `this` in `thing2()`.
```

If you were to do the same test above here:

```
obj.thing2() // `this` is `obj`

const fn = obj.thing2
fn() // `this` the global object, which is probably not good.
```

Comment: TypeScript *could* enforce `thing2` being a method by making its type equivalent to `thing2: (this: typeof obj) => void`, but doesn't.

Comment: Nope, that errors with `An arrow function cannot have a 'this' parameter.(2730)` [See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGUAWAlmAOYCMAXDABQCUqAfDAK5gAmApgGZHusA0MAPSCAKoQgwCEqAE8ADu1yESFanRSMWHbmF7YlRYgCZaGGACd2UJubAwAvgKGjxk6fMX5DJmpQBuIASs+l4kAMyUVF4QlLIKIJxwSOqM6BZWNnaOOMLs5uYg5pj2ANyYQA)

Comment: I meant as a type definition (e.g. in an `interface`), not as a literal value - like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4ChnLAC1AHMAmALmQAoDgBnCsATwAcIB7GZNgIwCsBKZAF4AfMgBubYABMA3FgC+WBGxC0wXPhXRDMOPIRClKgjMigQwAVyghkShfKw9eAOhpGSJ5AHofyAAMaWgDkOkCXAOVVdWQYO10Xd0NSLHiTIA)

Comment: Ah, of course :) It probably just omits the this type where it's implicit since that would be a lot of noise in the displayed types that is usually fairly obvious.